# Spawn a blender file in Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, simulation, urdf, blender

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had created a 3D model in Blender and had managed to spawn it in Gazebo, but an error occurred and I had to format my computer. After the format with the same source code I am not able to spawn the model in Gazebo. My urdf is:

```
 <inertial>
   <mass value="100.0" />
   <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
  <inertia  ixx="1.0" ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"  iyy="1.0"  iyz="0.0"  izz="1.0" />

 </inertial>

 <visual>
   <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
   <geometry>
     <mesh filename="package://gazebo_worlds/Media/models/pinky.3ds" />
   </geometry>
 </visual>

 <collision>
   <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
   <geometry>
     <mesh filename="package://gazebo_worlds/Media/models/pinky.3ds" />
   </geometry>
 </collision>
```

What is wrong? When I rosrun, no errors occurre but no model appears in Gazebo either.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35239/spawn-a-blender-file-in-gazebo/) by [Penny](https://answers.ros.org/users/1547/penny/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-05-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You try to use a 3D Studio (.3ds) format file. Gazebo only supports the .stl and COLLADA (.dae) formats. You should be able to export your model to .dae (or .stl, for that matter) using Blender and then use that in your URDF.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1